# iotop script does not work via custom script execution

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have CSF installed (configure safe firewall), it has a function to allow you to have custom scripts executed on load average events.

My script:

```
##!/usr/bin/env bash
iotop -bto --iter=1 2>&1 | mail -s "$HOSTNAME iotop output" incidents@
```

It works fine via bash shell but when executed by lfd (the monitoring process of CSF), I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/iotop", line 9, in <module>
    from iotop.ui import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 13, in
<module>
    from iotop.data import find_uids, TaskStatsNetlink, ProcessList, Stats
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/iotop/data.py", line 36, in
<module>
    from iotop import ioprio, vmstat
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/iotop/ioprio.py", line 52, in
<module>
    __NR_ioprio_get = find_ioprio_syscall_number(IOPRIO_GET_ARCH_SYSCALL)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/iotop/ioprio.py", line 38, in
find_ioprio_syscall_number
    bits = platform.architecture()[0]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/platform.py", line 1073, in architecture
    output = _syscmd_file(executable, '')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/platform.py", line 1021, in _syscmd_file
    rc = f.close()
IOError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Internally it calls an equivalent of:

```
import os
import sys

f = os.popen('file -b "%s" 2> %s' % (sys.executable, os.devnull))
f.read()
f.close()
```

For `popen()` to work it has to be able to get the `SIGCHLD` signal telling it that a child process exited. It seems that the environment that executes `iotop` has a custom reaper process that intercepts `SIGCHLD` and prevents python from getting notified about the process exiting. Thus when the function calls `.close()`, python tries to kill the process that is already dead and gets an error from the operating system.

If you cannot reconfigure the environment to let `SIGCHLD` pass, I think you'll have ro resort to ugly hacking.

Wrapping `iotop` in a script that monkey-patches `platform.architecture()` with a function that always returns the same tuple (something like `('64bit', 'ELF')`—consult the output of real `architecture()`) should let you progress.

Alternatively, you can just make a local copy of the `platform.py` file and edit that directly, setting `PYTHONPATH` for the cron job to point to that new file.

Comment: To make it more clear: I think the problem here is not related to `iotop` at all. It seems your environment is preventing `os.popen()` from working.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you have problems automating commands, it's because the thing that's running the command automatically does not have the same environment variables defined (because there's no login).  I don't think that's the case here, though.  I would sooner suspect the user that the script is running as doesn't have the same rights.

I would try to **su** to the user CSF is running the script as, and try running it manually as that user.